# Windows Remote logins available to test products?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is there anything simillar like Unix remote login's available for windows machines, say example I would like to test an application in windows 7 , which I don't have it installed or any virtual machines. Simply I would like to connect it to via RDP over internet and test it.

Is there any login's available for public use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of such a thing for Windows. I really doubt you'll find something like this, although the idea is interesting.

Comment: I too agree with that.

Comment: Unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is [Microsoft Office 2007 Test Drive](http://www.runaware.com/microsoft/en-us/microsoftoffice2007/td?action=launch_wizard_final):

> By launching the Test Drive, you will
>   be able to try out Microsoft Office
>   2007® including Word®, Excel®,
>   Outlook® and PowerPoint® on our
>   servers.

And there is also one for [MapPoint](http://www.runaware.com/microsoft/en-us/mappoint/td), and one for [Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/midsizebusiness/products/windowsvista/windows-vista-trial.aspx).
I don't know how well they work.

Comment: Thanks for the links @harrymc , I will look into those :)

Comment: The Office one was actually an RDP session into a Windows machine, runnign Office 2k7. However, it was an ActiveX control, so you necessarily have to have Windows for that to work. Didn't look at the others but they might work the same way.

Comment: This only works with IE on Windows. This is from Microsoft, after all.

Answer (score 0):

For some products, Microsoft distributes pre-made virtual machines with limited life-time for your testing. See [Microsoft VHD Test Drive Program Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb738373.aspx).

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing as what he wants; those VMs are usually huge.